# Eclipse IDE; Open in current window / instance?

Tags: eclipse, file, open-source, filesystems

I've been using Eclipse for about a week now and I'm loving it.. great software for the 'price'. :P However, I'm having a few issues getting started.

The most annoying, so far, has been opening files from outside of Eclipse, and having them set to open w/ Eclipse. When I open a file from the file-explorer or an external application (WinSCP for instance), Eclipse seemingly attempts to open an entirely new instance itself rather than opening the file within a currently running instance. Of course, because this is the case, Eclipse errors out w/ 'The workspace is currently in use. Please select another' (or whatever it says).

Is there a configuration option, or an argument that I can use when opening a file externally that will simply use the currently open instance of Eclipse?

Thx in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to open external file in the current Eclipse is to drag-n-drop it to the tabbed area where your files are displayed. You should consider that Eclipse is seriously geared towards using files as part of a project and opening random file with Eclipse is certainly possible but not encouraged.
To your question - since Eclipse runs in Java if you attempt to use eclipse.exe to open a file then script will always try to open a new instance, I don't know if what you want is actually doable

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

(Btw, I've upvoted your comment for the useful info, but I'm not marking as answered as it was a bit open-ended, and I'd like to see if somebody else has an actual solution.)

Answer (score 2):

To add to [DroidIn.net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135946/droidin-net)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061759/eclipse-ide-open-in-current-window-instance/2061860#2061860), here are a few eclipse bugs related to the question:

- [bug 4922](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4922) (from 2001!): "Need ability to open a file in eclipse from the command line", with sockent-monitoring kind of solutions, like the IBM proposition of [opening an RCP from an URL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-rcpurl/index.html), which leads to plugins like [EclipseCalls](http://www.jaylib.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/EclipsePlugins/EclipseCall).

  > EclipseCall is a plugin that accepts file-open requests on a defined socket port. A **specialized client can be used to open a file in Eclipse by command from outside Eclipse, e.g. by double clicking a source file in Windows Explorer**.
- [bug 178927](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=178927) (2007): "way to pass arguments from launcher to a running application instance", based on a modifier launcher (more Windows-oriented, although [bug 201154](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201154) is mac-oriented). An [OSGi-based solution](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/12/using-equinox-commandprovider-to-make.html) is also investigated.

(On Linux, see [also **steb**](http://community.buglabs.net/kgilmer/posts/114-Getting-the-files-into-Eclipse-steb))

Answer (score 0):

In a Mac terminal, you can use `open`, though I needed to point to the executable explicitly, since I have more than one Eclipse installed:

```
open -a ~/eclipse/java-oxygen/Eclipse.app  --args --launcher.openFile filename
```

You may or may not need `--launcher.openFile`, depending if you have `--launcher.defaultAction` set to `openFile` in your `eclipse.ini` [file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).  (This config-file edit is also what you need for double-clicking or "open-with" to use the running Eclipse.)

For instance, I could do this (with [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)) to open all of my failing tests after I'd copied to the clipboard (`pbpaste` is mac-specific):

```
pbpaste | parallel find . -name {}\\\* -print \
   | parallel open -a ~/eclipse/java-oxygen/Eclipse.app
```

The Eclipse file-opening documentation for all OSes is [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature).